# SFGUI rendering issue c++

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-glitch

I'm making a server menu system however when I remove all the items from the sfgui system and move on to another game state the labels from the previous game state are visible under a circumstance which I will explain in a minute, first let me show you the issue.

**Server Menu:**
[image: Server Menu.]

**Here you can see the issue:**
[image: Here you can see the issue]

The code for removal is as follows.

```
void S_ServerMenu::Exit() {
  ServerSelectWindow->Show(false);
  desktop.RemoveAll();
  desktop.Refresh();
}
```

However this issue only occurs on refresh of servers here is the code for refresh.

```
void S_ServerMenu::RefreshServers() {
  Document d;
  d.Parse<0>(LoadInServers().c_str());
  servers = ServerParser(d);
  ServerListTable->RemoveAll();
  ServerListTable->RefreshAll();
  for(int i = 0; i < servers.size(); i++) {
    auto label = sfg::Label::Create();

    label->SetText(servers[i].Name);

    MenuItem utm;
    utm.lbl = label;
    utm.index = i;
    utm.owner = this;
    label->SetAlignment(sf::Vector2f(0, 0));
    label->FontSize = 16;
    label->SetParent(ServerListTable);
    label->cont = ServerSelectWindowContainer;
    ServerListTable->Attach(label, sf::Rect<sf::Uint32>(1, i, 1, 1), sfg::Table::FILL | sfg::Table::EXPAND);

    label->GetSignal(sfg::Label::OnLeftClick).Connect(std::bind(&MenuItem::Clicked, utm));
  }
  ServerSelectWindow->RefreshAll();
}
```

Do any of you know how to solve this if so that would be great.

Comment: All I can say is, that you're using SFGUI wrong. I you should look at the provided example code in the SFGUI repository. Also did you edit the library? Because `label->cont` doesn't exist. As soon as you run your own modified version of any library, you're basically on your own.

Comment: Cont is just literally a shared pointer to a table. That shouldn't effect it.

Comment: So you did edit the library? If you start editing a library nobody will know whether you broke something by accident. But as I said, for the problem you should really look at the provided examples and adjust your code to that, instead of trying random things in hope it will work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a separate Desktop for each screen.